# Div not clearing on click?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, css

I'm making a basic webpage that uses PHP to pull data from a server and display its contents. The data is displaying just fine, but while the data loads, I want to include a loading message.

My intention is to, on click, clear the main div and display the message. Then, when the data is loaded, hide the loading message and display the data.

As of right now, the loading message is not being displayed at all, and the data from the last request stays displayed in the main div until the next bit of information is loaded.

Thank you for your help!

```js
function load(which, x) {
  $(".menu").css("background-color", "#E9967A");
  $(".menu").not(which).css("background-color", "#854F96");

document.getElementById("main").innerHTML = "";
document.getElementById("loading").show();

  $.ajax({
    url: "php/script.php",
    type: "post",
    data: {"data": x},
    success: function(response) {
      document.getElementById("Loading").hide();
      document.getElementById("main").innerHTML = response;
    }
  });
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.2.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="header"></div>

<div class="sidebar">
  <div class="menu" id="profile" onclick="load(this, 1)"></div>
  <div class="menu" id="cardbook" onclick="load(this, 2)"></div>
  <div class="menu" id="progress" onclick="load(this, 3)"></div>
  <div class="menu" id="achievements" onclick="load(this, 4)"></div>
</div>

<div id="main">
  <div id="loading" style="display:none;">
    Loading...
  </div>
</div>
```

## Edit 1

I've changed my JavaScript to the following. However, I'm still receiving the same results

```
<script>
    function load(which, x) {
        $(".menu").css("background-color", "#E9967A");
        $(".menu").not(which).css("background-color", "#854F96");

        $("#main").innerHTML = "";
        $("#loading").show();

        $.ajax({
            url: "php/script.php",
            type: "post",
            data: {"data": x},
            success: function(response) {
                $("#loading").hide();
                $("#main").innerHTML = response;
            }
        });
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Use `$("#loading").show();` or `$("#loading").hide();`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As `document.getElementById("Loading")` will return reference DOM element which doesn't have these method.

`.show()` and `.hide()` is jQuery methods, so create jQuery object to use them.

Use `$("#loading").show();` or `$("#loading").hide();`

```js
function load(which, x) {
  $(".menu").css("background-color", "#E9967A");
  $(".menu").not(which).css("background-color", "#854F96");

  $("#main").hide().html("");
  $("#loading").show();

  $.ajax({
    url: "php/script.php",
    type: "post",
    data: {
      "data": x
    },
    success: function(response) {
      $("#main").show().html(response);
      $("#loading").hide();
    }
  });
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.2.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="header"></div>

<div class="sidebar">
  <div class="menu" id="profile" onclick="load(this, 1)"></div>
  <div class="menu" id="cardbook" onclick="load(this, 2)"></div>
  <div class="menu" id="progress" onclick="load(this, 3)"></div>
  <div class="menu" id="achievements" onclick="load(this, 4)"></div>
</div>

<div id="main">
</div>
<div id="loading" style="display:none;">
  Loading...
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you for your quick reply. I made those changes, but I'm still getting the same result. Any more ideas?

Comment: Thank you again. However, I'm still not getting the intended results. To simplify it, I tried deleting the "loading" div all together, and just set the html of "main" to "loading" before the ajax script, then overwrite it on success. However, that didn't work either.

Comment: This is embarrassing. Yes, your answer works! Turns out I was editing the wrong file the whole time.